# Arima model for non-negative data

Tags: time-series, arima, data-transformation

I have been reading a [tutorial](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series/latest/a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.pdf) for an introduction to time series.

It contains a dataset, with an $Arima(2,0,0)$ forecast along with a 80% and 95% prediction interval. It looks like this:
[image]

This model was chosen due to the behaviour of the partial autocorrelation function ("it is zero after lag 2").

However, as the tutorial later explains, there is a clear problem with this modelling approach. The prediction interval predicts some negative values, which would be invalid for this data. (The data is assumed to be $\geq 0$). The forecast errors also have undesirable properties.

**My question: How would you address this issue?**

Some of my thoughts:

- transforming the data $x$ using $\log(x+1)$. Is this a respected method? Any pros / cons I should know about?
- any predicted values $<0$, naively set to zero. It feels, to me, like that there should be a better choice than this.

Comment: What are the values themselves? Are they counts? Rates? something else?

Comment: Non negative real numbers

Comment: Okay, I've located it myself. It's the volcanic dust veil index in the northern
hemisphere, from 1500-1969 (original data from Hipel and Mcleod, 1994); data is at http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/annual/dvi.dat ; the discussion starts on the page labelled p52 of the linked document (56th physical page of 75 pages)

Comment: The data series has many exact zeroes in it, but values that are not zero  are often large; the smallest nonzero value is 5.

Comment: I wouldn't use ARIMA on this series as-is; the long stretches of exact zeroes and the lower bound of zero require a different approach. I might be inclined to treat the zeroes as censored (the actual level of volcanic dust is probably just below some detection limit). It *might* be that some ARIMA model on the log-scale with some proper account of that effect may be reasonable, but that's a relatively hard data set to model. (I wouldn't use it to teach someone ARIMA.)

Comment: If you want to try to transform it to model it as ARIMA, a square root transform would seem to be about as well as you can do, but I wouldn't think it would be especially successful.